# go ignoring vendor directory

Tags: windows, go, vendor, gopath

Everything I read about the vendor directory gives me the understanding that if I have a directory:

```
$GOPATH/src/vendor
```

And put my dependencies in there (I am using godeps), when doing `go run`, go should check in that directory first.

If I run my code in a Docker image I have, this works fine. However now that I try to run the same code on my Windows machine, go simply ignores the `vendor/` directory, and fails to find the dependencies.

What am I doing wrong?

```
main.go:7:2: cannot find package "gopkg.in/alecthomas/kingpin.v2" in any of:
        C:\Go\src\gopkg.in\alecthomas\kingpin.v2 (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\js\dev\my_project\rest\src\gopkg.in\alecthomas\kingpin.v2 (from $GOPATH)
        C:\Users\js\dev\go\src\gopkg.in\alecthomas\kingpin.v2
```

Is the output when I try to do:

```
go run main.go
```

A directory `vendor/` exists in this directory.

```
go version go1.7 windows/amd64
```

---

The exact commands I run (in windows cmd.exe)

```
> cd C:\Users\js\dev\my_project\rest\
> set GOPATH=C:\Users\js\dev\my_project\rest\;c:\Users\js\dev\go

> cd src
> dir
...
2016-09-01  23:20             2 923 main.go
...
2016-09-03  01:27    <DIR>          vendor

> go run main.go
```

Comment: You were quick, but I just realised I forgot it and added it before I saw your comment. go1.7

Comment: And where exactly is your `main.go`?

Comment: `$GOPATH/src/main.go` and `$GOPATH/src/vendor/`... This exact same `vendor` dir works when I mount the exact same directory in Docker.

Comment: To be clear: `cd C:\Users\js\dev\my_project\rest\src\` then `set GOPATH=C:\Users\js\dev\my_project\rest\src\;C:\Users\js\dev\go` after that I do `go run main.go`

Comment: Don't use `go run`, and make sure you go source is in a directory in GOPATH. There's also not much point in putting the vendor outside your project directory, since the idea is you vendor the dependencies for your project.

Comment: Why shouldn't I use `go run`? Also `go build` gives the same issue. And as I state my source is in `GOPATH`, under `$GOPATH/src/` specifically.

Comment: `go run` operates on single files, not packages, so it's a common point of confusion around GOPATH issues. Your main.go is not in an import directory. You shouldn't have any source files in GOPATH/src

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this did not work is because you are not supposed to put any code directly into the `$GOPATH/src/` directory.

The solution is to put your project into a sub-directory like so:

`$GOPATH/src/app/*.go`

Answer (score 1):

Seems your `GOPATH` is incorrect?
The `GOPATH` should specify the location of your workspace i.e. directory containing `src`, `pkg` and `bin` directories at its root.

Try doing

> set GOPATH=C:\Users\js\dev\my_project\rest\;c:\Users\js\dev\go

More details at: https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Comment: Sorry I had made a typo when writing the example of what I am writing. This does not work either, it never checks the vendor directory. I had set the path like you suggest all along... In my example I accidentally added `src/` at the end

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to understand is that `godep save` is simply copying dependencies from your `$GOPATH` to a `vendor` directory inside your project.

You will have to `go get` your dependencies first. After you have them in `$GOPATH`, you can do a `godep save` to copy the current version to your project, and be assured that even if the version in `$GOPATH` changes, you will have a fixed version in your project until you explicitly change it  via `godep`.

So, if I have a $GOPATH of `/home/me/go_workspace`, and a project called `$GOPATH/src/github.com/project_x` with a dependency of `github.com/you/xyz`, then I would do `go get github.com/you/xyz`, and `godep save` from within my project directory.  This would create a `vendor` folder with the dependency at its current commit inside.

Comment: This does not help with my problem however. I have done `go get` and `godep save`. The dependencies are there in the `vendor/` directory. Everything works fine with this setup if I run inside of my Docker, it uses the dependencies in the `vendor/` directory. But if I instead run it on Windows, exact same directory and files, it doesn't look in `vendor/`

Comment: Did you try setting GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1 in your environment explicitly?  You shouldn't have to, but it's not impossibly that you hit a bug, and might be worth a quick try.

Comment: You should also ensure that your version of `godep` is up to date.  I have `godep v74 (darwin/amd64/go1.7)`.  I ran into some trouble when I had an outdated `godep`.

Comment: Yes I actually tried that already. And I retried it now, but no help. (In regards to using GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1)

Comment: Ok, but I shouldn't need godep at all should I? It is just there as a help. As I understand it, I could manually create a `vendor/` dir and copy stuff there myself (I haven't, but that should work)

Comment: I'm not sure about that. For what it's worth, I generally create a binary for each platform I'm interested in and execute it (rather than using `go run`).  Something like:  `env GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o bin/$(BINNAME).darwin` for mac and `env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o bin/$(BINNAME).linux`.  Hopefully this isn't making you chase your tail around :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122552/discussion-between-jxstanford-and-joakim).